# sails-sqlserver: multiple sql servers on same host

Tags: sails.js

I'm using sails-sqlserver where my host is running both SQL Server 2008 and 2012. In connections.js - host: is set to 'SQLServerhost\2012' I am getting the error "error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!" Is there a different way to specify which SQL Server to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

I've found success with the below format in `/config/connections.js` when I need to work with *different databases* on the *same* server (but see below suggestion):

```
sqlserverLOCAL: {
    adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'localhost',       // Name or IP Address of SQL Server
    port: '1433',
    database: 'YourDBName'   // i.e. Initial Catalog
},

sqlserver: {
    adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    host: '11.222.333.444',  // IP Address of SQL Server
    port: '1433',
    database: 'OtherDBName'  // i.e. Initial Catalog
}
```

In your case, perhaps setting both `host:` attributes to the *same* server (just `SQLServerhost` rather than `SQLServerhost\2012`) and then set the `database:` attribute to the appropriate Initial Catalog would be best. Also, **make sure you double-check what ports the two SQL Servers are running on** and set that attribute value accordingly.

Comment: I have tried the following:

theSqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'pwd',
    host: '172.17.252.82',
    port: '49254',
    database: 'mydb',
    options: {
      encrypt: false   // set to true for Azure databases 
    }

but still get the error:

Loading the app's models and any custom adapters...
Loading app models...
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
Lowering sails...

Comment: You might temporarily try setting `migrate:` to safe in `/config/models.js`

    module.exports.models = {

      migrate: 'safe'
  
    };

More tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524926/the-hook-orm-taking-too-long-to-load/35414335#35414335

Comment: @ArnieP, Did you figure anything out on your settings? Did you try my `migrate:` suggestion?