# Error: The hook `orm` is taking too long to load

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

whenever trying to lifting sails it gives me the hookTimeout error every time. 
While for the same configuration settings it's perfectly running on other systems.

using Ubuntu 16.0.4 and Manjaro
nodejs version 7.4.0
sails version 0.12.11
Mongodb version 3.4.1

the complete error report is like this.

> info: Starting app...
>
> error: Grunt :: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/util.rb:1109: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>
> error: Grunt :: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/util.rb:1109: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>
> error: Error: The hook `orm` is taking too long to load.
>
> Make sure it is triggering its `initialize()` callback, or else set `sails.config.orm._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 60000)
>       at Timeout.tooLong [as _onTimeout] (/home/navalk/PV/provakil/sails/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:92:21)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524926/the-hook-orm-taking-too-long-to-load

Comment: @spickermann  tried all the possible solution described at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524926/the-hook-orm-taking-too-long-to-load]

Answer (score 0):

Try do cut your last created/changed model.
If won't help, try to cut one by one and move to another folder.
You will then find if it is issue with some of your models or really with sails.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing hook timeout in local.js 
`hookTimeout    : 30000,`