# how to connect arangodb with sails

Tags: sails.js, arangodb

I'm trying to using sails-arangodb to connect sails to arangodb. I follow this guide: [Arangodb use case guide](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Cookbook/UseCases/SailsJS.html) to connect to arangodb. But i face error:

```
error: Error: The hook `orm` is taking too long to load. Make sure it
is triggering its `initialize()` callback, or else set `sails.conf
g.orm._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 20000)
at Timeout.tooLong [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\thanhtv\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
e_modules\sails\lib\app\private\loadHooks.js:85:21)
at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
```

here is my connections.js

```
    module.exports.connections = {

    localArangoDB: {
        adapter: 'sails-arangodb',
        host: '192.168.0.152',
        port: 8529,
//        user: 'root',
//        password: 'root',
        database: {
            name: 'test',
            graph: 'test'
        }
//        database: 'test',
//
//        graph: 'test', // ArangoDB specific 
//        collection: 'test', // ArangoDB specific 
    },

};
```

and here is my models.js

```
module.exports.models = {

    connection: 'localArangoDB',

    migrate: 'alter'

};
```

I'm i missing something ?

Comment: I don't think you have any issues with your database configuration. It looks like you just need to extend your hook timeout time. See more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524926/the-hook-orm-taking-too-long-to-load)